# Как вывести или объединить 2 json в php?

Tags: php, json

Есть 2 JSON по типу:

```
"item":
[{      "id": "550",
      "name": "Серега"
}]
```

И второй JSON:

```
"item":
[{      "id": "550",
       "city": "LA"
}].
```

Собственно, как их вывести в одном цикле? Чтоб по `id` подставлялись недостающие ключи и значения, либо привести их к виду:

```
  "item":
        [{      "id": "550",
                "name": "Серега",
                "city": "LA"
        }].
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a = json_decode('{"item":
[{      "id": "550",
      "name": "Серега"
}]}', true);
$b = json_decode('{"item":
[{      "id": "550",
       "city": "LA"
}]}', true);

print_r(array_replace_recursive($a, $b));
```

Все гениальное, просто)

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно создать отдельный массив, куда вы внесёте все общие значения.
Через `$data[]=...`

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = '{"item":
[{      "id": "550",
      "name": "Серега"
},
{      "id": "551",
      "name": "Серег"
}]}';

$b = '{"item":
[{      "id": "550",
       "city": "LA"
},
{      "id": "551",
      "city": "LA"
}]}';
// Get assoc arrays
$a_val = json_decode($a, true);
$b_val = json_decode($b, true);
$arr = [];

foreach($a_val['item'] as $k => $v){
   // Merge array
   $arr [] = array_merge($a_val['item'][$k], $b_val['item'][$k]);
}

// Create new JSON with array
$res = json_encode(['item' => $arr], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
print_r($res);
```

- `json_decode(array, assoc)` - получаем ассоциативный массив
- `array_merge(arr1, arr2)` - соединяет два или более массива
- `json_encode(array)` - возвращает JSON - представление данных

[Почитать о array_merge](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: Он просто их объединяет.

Comment: @Senbonzakuraa поглащает существующие и добавляет новые.

Answer (score 0):

Можно декодировать json с помощью [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php) и использовать [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-merge.php).